# Removing the "Earth Engine Apps Experimental" logo

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Is there a way to remove or hide the "Earth Engine Apps Experimental" logo found in published Earth Engine Apps?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can set up your own Earth Engine GUI with [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/app_engine_intro), which is completely customizable.